# Round button size disabled in IB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

Is there a way to change the size of a round style button in Interface Builder (OSX project)? I'm trying to achieve something like the Run/Stop button in Xcode toolbar. When I drop a round button onto the toolbar and go to the Size inspector, width and height are disabled. I only need to increase the size of buttons and add image to it.

Do I need to create a custom view and drop it onto the toolbar?

Comment: What do you mean by "round button"? A UIBarButtonItem, as it should be used for a toolBar? In this case, you could set its width in IF, but not its height, which is given be the toolBar height.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner The post is tagged [tag:cocoa], **not** [tag:cocoa-touch].  He's talking about OS X programming, not iOS programming.

Comment: @rob mayoff: Thanks for the hint, I was not aware of this!